# Android Studio not rendering the SignInButton <item> tag requires a 'android:color' attribute

Tags: android, google-plus

Google SignInButton is not being rendered on Android Studio's preview pane. An error is being shown and I'm not figuring out what is happening. I just want to implement a Google Login, but this is preventing me from being able to.

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rleote.googlelogin"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
}
```

And this is how I'm referencing the SignInButton in my activity:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

The error in the preview pane is this:
Exception Details android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find drawable resource matching value 0x7FFF001C (resolved name: common_signin_btn_text_dark) in current configuration.   at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:699)   at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getColorStateList(BridgeResources.java:210)   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.q.c  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.q.a  at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.a  at
...
Failed to configure parser for C:\Users\Rodrigo\Source\Repos\googlelogin\GoogleLogin\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.1.71\res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #5:  tag requires a 'android:color' attribute
...

Looks like it is not being able to parse common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml because of a missing color atribute. But I didn't define this drawable. Looks like this is a component from google services, why would this be missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What API version do you have selected in the preview pane?

Comment: The api 21 is selected in the preview pane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out a workaround for this. Basically the error is stating that the drawing file doesn't have a required android:color attribute. However, I didn't want to add a custom color. Then I get the path to the drawing file res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml and saw that it was like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark" />
</selector>
```

You can notice there is no color attribute. Then I saw that the path res\color had a few files, and one of them is a common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml, containing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_disabled" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_focused" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_disabled" />
    <item
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default" />
</selector>
```

The difference is the color tag and no drawable. However, drawable is also mandatory. What I did was to "merge" both into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark"
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed"/>

    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark"
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_disabled"/>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark"
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_focused" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark"
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_disabled" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark"
        android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default" />
</selector>
```

I still would like an explanation if I'm doing it right or this should work automatically. This looks pretty much like a workaround instead of a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 4):

Running the gradle task `buildDependents` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a test project with this setup and do see the same error in the designer. However, the app runs as expected without any issues. My conclusion is that this is an Android Studio/Google Play Services SDK bug that you should be able to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue, not sure about the cause of it, but changing "minSdkVersion" from 14 to 17 in build.gradle(app) and building project fixed it for me.

P.S. While debugging on device, button renders fine with any of those SDK versions, seems like IDE problem